# AWS CDK - access to the new features

Tags: python-3.x, typescript, aws-cdk

AWS CDK being a relatively new tool might have some missing high level constructs (such as NACL as the time of writing this question - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3621).

My understanding is that AWS CDK is developed using Typescript.

Would selecting Typescript as the IaC language give faster access (compared to python, other) to the newly available constructs?

Pre-release/Dev versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDK is released with all bindings at the same time. So choosing one particular language won't provide any benefit. There's one exception though: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/assert

The **assert** package is only available for Typescript as far as I know. I personally use Python and miss this package *a lot*. Unit testing CDK infrastructure is very ugly without native support.

Comment: Good answer, with the unit testing you might try [LocalStack](https://localstack.cloud/).

Answer (score 2):

**My understanding is that AWS CDK is developed using Typescript.**

That's correct, from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html

> Why do you need Node.js when you're a Python, C♯, or Java developer?
>
> The AWS CDK is developed in TypeScript and transpiled to JavaScript. Bindings for the other supported languages make use of the AWS CDK engine running on Node.js, as does the cdk command-line tool.

**Would selecting Typescript as the IaC language give faster access (compared to python, other) to the newly available constructs?**

There would have to be a very good reason why a new feature is not exposed at the same time to all languages. All we know is the bindings for the other languages use the CDK running on Node.js - so it looks like NodeJS would be first cab off the rank if any.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I agree. Yet I was not able to find any indication of the intent to release the new features across all supported stacks at the same time. Have I missed it? Or, alternatively, have you seen an indication that the cross language bindings are auto generated? I suspect so, but again, would like to see it openly stated in writing. Thank you!

Comment: I attended a talk last week and the AWS presenter was asked if the CDK was based around the CLI. And he said it wasn't 'entirely' but more importantly he talked about some spec, a DDD and how not even all CloudFormation is complete compared to the CLI. Judging from the CLI though, it doesn't matter what language you use. Sure there's ongoing check-ins but all major CLI releases have the same APIs to all languages. At the moment with CDK it's too hard to tell, only a month ago they said Java and C# was'in preview'. We'll soon see but AWS are big on Python.